# How to know if a series of events are the result of chance or a good selection strategy?

Tags: probability, distributions, binomial-distribution, predictor

My question is: How to know if a series of events are the result of chance or a good selection strategy?

For example there are 5 events with diferents probabilities for to be A or B:

```
             A                 B    
event 1     30%                 70 % 

event 2     10%                 90 % 

event 3     60%                 40 % 

event 4     70%                 30 % 

event 5     15%                 85 %
```

My strategy select in this way: event 1)A 2)A 3)b 4)A 5)B and the result are (ok if I made a correct selection) :

```
event 1     OK         
event 2     OK        
event 3     OK        
event 4     NOOK        
event 5     OK
```

Then, how to know if it was product of the a good strategy or only good luck?

Actually I make it in this way:

---

First I calculate of mean of  the Probabilities of my choices:

```
   (0,3 + 0,1 + 0,4 + 0,7 + 0,85)/5 = 0,47
```

then I Calculate the probability with binomial probability:

```
  in excel: =DISTR.BINOM.N(3;5;0,47;1) = 0,847753953
```

then the probability to have 4 or 5 correct selections for good luck is only 0,152246047. It´s a good strategy

---

But I feel it is not the best way to do.

Am I wrong?

What is the best way?

Comment: I don't understand the situation. What are these probabilities? Why would picking A or B be better?

Answer (score 2):

The phenomena you are, in part, referring to can be described as *the hot hands* phenomena. *Hot hands* is a reference to an American sport, basketball, in which a shooter is perceived as having a series of successful shot in a sequence or string. Making a determination as to whether that "perspective" or opinion is luck or skill has been the basis for many, many research papers over the years.

Until recently, it was assumed that the "hot hands" phenomenon was a fallacy and, equivalently, that the likelihood of having "hot hands" was modeled by the long-run, unconditional and independent probability of a binomial success. I use the word "recently" because a 2015 paper titled *A Cold Shower for the Hot Hand Fallacy* by Miller and Sanjuro (see here ... https://asfee2015.sciencesconf.org/61541/document) convincingly overturned this long-held belief. They demonstrate that basing "hot hands" on an unconditional likelihood was the mistake. The correct approach is to condition a sequence of shots on the occurrence of a "successful" shot, in other words, a conditional probability. With this insight, they correctly conclude that the "hot hands fallacy" is in fact itself fallacious. "Hot hands" really do exist -- they are not an artifact or luck.

This was originally reported on Andrew Gelman's blog although I don't have a citation for it.